# Save for Web & Devices in Illustrator CS5 Causes Artifacts on Large Files

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, gradient, visual-artifacts

I am saving with these settings:

[image]

And ending up with weird transparent line artifacts:

[image]

The `ai` file does not have this, and the path has nothing near the place where the lines are showing:

[image]

From what I can tell it has to do with rendering the gradient as it appears the line is showing across a color band location, but who knows. How can I prevent this from happening?

**UPDATE**

I tried saving with a layer underneath it and the same problem occurred, but in a different spot?!?!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GD!  Out of curiosity...  is AI fully patched and current, and does it happen at smaller sizes?

Comment: AI is CS5 and fully up-to-date. It doesn't happen at small sizes at all.

Comment: Random lines could possibly be bad RAM. I've used SFW with files up to 90 inches and not seen your issue. Are seeing the artifacts in the saved image or just in the SFW preview?

Comment: In the saved image unfortunately. And it always is appearing at the same spot.

Comment: Have you tried simply moving the artwork a bit to adjust it's placement on the artboard?

Comment: Yes. Same results... different result when layers are underneath it though... updating the question.

Comment: Interesting. I'd love to test the file. Is that bevel a 3D effect? Have you tried expanding that if it is?

Comment: As a workaround... what happens if you open the AI file in Photoshop and save for web there?

Comment: You should add the workaround as an answer as it solved the problem. email me at info@urbanapps.com and I will send you the file for curiosities sake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the Illustrator file with Photoshop. Then save for web via Photoshop.

Illustrator's vector to pixel conversion can have very odd hiccups at times. There are cases which have no underlying issue to directly solve and appear more like "gremlins" than bug sor direct issues.

Opening the file in Photoshop allows Photoshop to do the vector to pixel conversion and often results in slightly better results. This is especially true if you're seeing one of these "gremlins" in a piece.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the Photoshop-fix works.

Another solution that sometimes works for me is resizing the graphic to 99%. This forces AI to re-render, and sometimes the artifacts are gone.
Of course, this can only be done if the actual size in pixels can deviate by a tiny amount.

Just leaving this here for future passers-by who don't have (or don't want to use) Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a way around this, unfortunately its a few extra steps, but it allows you to stay within AI.

1. Select all elements on the artboard.
2. Group > reflect horizontal
3. save as a .svg
4. open it up and reflect back to original layout and save however

So far this is working, I use to move the artboard or project elements on the artboard around countless times to where the final result was acceptable at best.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue, but once I installed an update from Adobe, the problem was resolved. 
(Or at least I haven't come across it again.)